# How to deploy repository in Apache Geronimo 3.0.1

Tags: apache, geronimo

I am new `Apache Geronimo`.I read the following [link](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/configuring-multiple-repositories.html) for deploying repository. Even I don't know where will these concept will be useful. just i am learning.

I created sub-directory under  and created `.xml` file according to the above link.

here, I faced the problem while deploying time. `deploy(.bat) deploy <GERONIMO_HOME>/repo2/repo2.xml` command is not working.

```
 <GERONIMO_HOME>=C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.1
```

I run the following command for deploying.but it's not working.

```
deploy(.bat) deploy C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/geronimo-tomcat7-javaee6-3.0.1/repo2/repo2.xml
```

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do following bellow steps:
1. Log in to the Administrative Console
2. Select Advanced on left bar
3. Go to Resources -> Repository